# www going to the wrong domain

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd.conf

So I have two sites on one **plesk** server set out as below:

/var/www/vhosts/site1.co.uk

and

/var/www/vhosts/site2.co.uk

The problem is both www.site1.co.uk and www.site2.co.uk are both going to /var/www/vhosts/site1.co.uk.

This is illustrated below:
[image]

The http conf file for site1 is:
http://laravel.io/bin/6mr7E

The http conf files for site2 is
http://laravel.io/bin/XLKBO

Can anyone see a solution.

Comment: try to define a apache default virtualhost

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of your vhosts contain any reference (ServerAlias) to www. for any of the domains so when you access any site with www in front, it will go to the default vhost in Apache (which is the first one that it finds when parsing the configuration for that IP:PORT).

Go to Plesk and somewhere in the hosting setup for each domain you should have a tickbox to allow the domain to be browsable with www. as well. If not, just add the www.domain as an alias, but that's just a hackish solution.